# SignUp User via AWS Lambda & Cognito (Serverless Architecture)

Tags: javascript, authentication, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I am working with the **Serverless Framework** in my approach to Authentication.  My goal is to create an API endpoint that triggers (via AWS API Gateway) a Lambda Function that creates a new AWS Cognito user.  The endpoint will have a custom authorizer to protect it.

My Lambda function is below.  When it's run, I receive the error *"NotAuthorizedException: SignUp is not permitted for this user pool"*. Any thought on how to authorize my Lambda function to create a new user?

```
'use strict';

var AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
var CognitoUserPool = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool;
var CognitoUserAttribute = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute;

module.exports.init = (event, context, callback) => {

  console.log('Lambda initiated with event:',event);

  // Define AWS Cognito User Pool
  var poolData = {
    "UserPoolId": process.env['COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID'],
    "ClientId": process.env['COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID']
  };
  var userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
  console.log('userPool:',userPool);

  // Define User Attributes
  var attributeList = [];
  var dataEmail = {
    "Name": "email",
    "Value": "email@example.com"
  };
  var attributeEmail = new CognitoUserAttribute(dataEmail);
  attributeList.push(attributeEmail);
  console.log('attributeList:',attributeList);

  // Create User via AWS Cognito
  userPool.signUp('username', 'password', attributeList, null, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('err:',err);
      callback(err,null);
    } else {
      console.log('result:',result);
      cognitoUser = result.user;
      console.log('user name is ' + cognitoUser.getUsername());
      callback(null,result);
    }
  });

};
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"NotAuthorizedException: SignUp is not permitted for this user pool" exception is thrown when the user pool only allows administrators to create the users via the AdminCreateUser API. With this setting enabled, SignUp API cannot be called and will throw this error.

If you are calling this from a lambda trigger you can use AdminCreateUser API or disable this setting so your user pool allows SignUp API calls.

Answer (score 6):

As [Chean Mehta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3204480/chetan-mehta) pointed out, you can disable the AdminCreateUser setting for SignUp API to work, for that you have to set `AllowAdminCreateUserOnly` to `false` in your serverless cognito configuration or you can disable this by following these steps:

1. Go to your cognito console.
2. Select your user pool.
3. Select Policies under General settings.
4. Select **Allow users to sign themselves up**
5. and Save changes

[image]